# Android custom tabs

Tags: android

I want 4 tabs in my app but I don't want to show default tabs. I want to have something like dragging tabs. When I click on first tab and does not pick my finger up and drags to next tab and so on.

[image]

The tab bar like this above. When I press on one tab I can move to another tab as well by this moving of finger.

Comment: Ok, but what is your question?

Comment: try this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/) may be useful to u

Comment: I have attached one image which shows the tab style i want to implement

Answer (score 0):

> i Want to have something like dragging tabs

What if the component which will do what you need, is not named "tab" in API?

It is a little bit more work, but you can use your imagination an implement a custom components which parent it is a...Image Gallery? - that component which shows an animated thumbnail of images when you scroll.

Or put in a scroll ScrollView a LinearLayout and a few image buttons...?

Some custom tabs here: [Custom tabs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903796/custom-tabs-in-android)