# How to set the height of the tab and how to set the font of the label in Android? 

Tags: android, tabs

In my app I am using the tab layout.I want to modify the default height of the tab and I want to modify the tab label font without using customized tab. Is it possible?  If yes, then how to implement it. Can anybody suggest me

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity 
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost                            
        addTab(tabHost,"Find Gifts","findgifts",R.drawable.findgifts,R.layout.tabs_bg);
        }


    public static void addTab(TabHost host, String title, String tag,
            int drawable, int layout) {
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec(tag);
        spec.setContent(layout);
        View view = prepareTabView(host.getContext(), title, drawable);
        spec.setIndicator(view);
        host.addTab(spec);

    }

    private static View prepareTabView(Context context, String title,
            int drawable) {
         View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);

         ImageView tabicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabicon);
         tabicon.setImageResource(drawable);

         TextView tabtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
         tabtext.setText(title);             

          return view;
    }
  }
```

Trace:

```
10-04 13:13:43.851: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3734): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tab/com.example.tab.HelloTabWidget}:  

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2130903042

10-04 13:13:43.851: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3734): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code adjusts the height on the tabs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++)

{
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 33; 
}
```

Comment: How to set the font of the text?

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources which I can point you to:

- [Custom tabs tutorial](http://ondrejcermak.info/programovani/custom-tabs-in-android-tutorial/comment-page-1/)
- [Google code project](http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/) for custom tabs with enhancements
- Another [tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903796/custom-tabs-in-android/3904011#3904011)

edit:

The view that you are trying to `findViewById()` is not present in `R.layout.main`

Comment: Yes, if you want to modify the look and feel, you have to use some form of customization.