# On an Android tab, how to show the text under the image?

Tags: android, image, text, tabs, android-tabhost

I have an Android application that uses tabs.
I already have the tabs, and the Activities correctly on the application.
My problem is that, when I add the text and image on the tab, the text appears over the image.[(EXAMPLE)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/Capture.PNG)
What I want is the text to appear bellow the image. This happens either if I use the image or a selector.
I use this code to add the tab to the tabHost:

```
// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CategoryListActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.category_title)).setIndicator(getString(R.string.category_title), res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_category)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the default behaviour is that (see some example here: http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-tabbed-activities/)

The recommended tab images are darkish to avoid that, using white and grey as font color.

To change that you will have to create custom tabs:

[Custom tabs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903796/custom-tabs-in-android)