# how to make shuch an android tab?

Tags: android

I want to make a tab menu as in this link https://www.justinmind.com/usernote/tests/10582408/10582411/10582413/index.html#/screens/74bd08d4-2de1-4149-b45e-c648c36ccdd5
I have mazed from searching through out every simillar questions in deferent sites without any useful answer , I can not remove the bottom-line of tabs and with or change its color and make border surround other tabs and make its background white as designed at the link above

Comment: Your question is too general, and contains a lot of sub question.I suggest you break your problem in to smaller tasks (how to navigate within the app (fragments/Activities) how to add the buttons and how to link them)

Comment: no linking in not the issue, what I mean is only the design, how to design such a tabMenu? is it posible using android styles only?

Comment: -1 low quality question

Comment: I'll take these notes into consideration for next questions, tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904011/2140191

In your /res/layout folder should be a file with the layout (custom look) for your tabs.

This websites gives a tutorial about customization of tabs:

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: I think these stuff will help me alot . thank you alot for your helping and bringing me out from this maze, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The one in the link does not seem to be tabs. I think it's a customized layout.
One way to go about this is have a three label field with white background and line drawn in between may be using view with background gray. On click even u can animate and change the content.

Comment: and you mean that the three lables should be repeated in each page?

Comment: It depends on you how you want to design. I would have everything in a single activity, on click of the button, I would change the contents using hide and show. And I may use fragments if needed.